# build gpuocelot fails due to boost linkage errors on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: boost, cuda, x86, osx-snow-leopard, amd-processor

I used the latest trunk version of [gpuocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/) on a mac snow 10.6.8 with gcc 4.5.3 and boost @1.49.0_0+universal (active) (boost installed via macports).

I run scons and I get

```
.release_build/ocelot/ptx.os .release_build/ocelot/ptxgrammar.os -L/usr/lib -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt -ldl ld: library not found for -lboost_system-mt collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423096/when-trying-to-build-gpuocelot-running-into-boost-link-errors-on-os-x-lion) reports failure on OS X Lion.
anyone with similar issue?

Comment: Have you built multi-threaded variant of Boost.System?

Comment: no, I installed boost @1.49.0_0+universal. why do I have to build a  multi-threaded variant of Boost?

Comment: please read Boost manual. While most of boost libraries are header-only, several libraries (like Boost.System, Boost.Thread etc) need to be built. I don't know what "boost @1.49.0_0+universal" is, but if it doesn't contain pre-built libs, you should build them on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this command line instead:

```
.release_build/ocelot/ptx.os .release_build/ocelot/ptxgrammar.os -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt -ldl
```

Indeed, on my system, Mac ports installs boost libraries in **/opt/local/lib** instead of /usr/lib.

Comment: thanks, i should have noticed that my ports are as well at /opt/local/lib . substitute w/ this path is not straightfwd though

Answer (score 0):

Enter the gpuocelot/ocelot/scripts directory and modify the build_environment.py accordingly (in my  case put the proper path for boost in function

> def getBoost(env):